# Why is it "sheet music" and not "musical sheet"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I always had problem in understanding the reason people call it *sheet music*. Isn't it a sheet (an object) that has an adjective of being related to music? We don't say things like *sheet Excel*, or *sheet cheat*. The correct syntax or grammar of English tells us that we should use the adjective before the noun. So, why don't we call it *music sheet*?

Comment: Thanks for the question! I'm going to migrate this over to English Language and Usage, since it's more of an etymology question than a musical one.

Comment: To me a "Music Sheet" would be bedding that plays `Here Comes the Sun` when I get out of it in the morning. :-)

Comment: Great note. But context always plays an important role in our communication. Without context, and based on the similar grounds, _plays `Here Comes the Sun`_ is a game, rather than playing music. :)

Comment: I'm always dismayed by foreign language education that leads people to think that the standard term for something must somehow be "incorrect" because it doesn't follow a general pattern in the language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, 'music' is in fact the pluralization, and 'sheet' is an adjective describing the music.

So, rather than "A sheet of type: music," we're talking about "Music (pl.) in sheet form."

**Edit:**
Really, the whole construct is the noun, and there are many other cases like this where the object itself comes second. For example, there are some big differences between 'print fine' and 'fine print' or 'bass string' and 'string bass'. Essentially, you're right that the describing word comes first, but you need to understand that the term *sheet music* is referring to a more abstract definition of 'music'.

*Sheet music* is essentially synonymous with 'notation', as in "Do you have the notation for that song?" We would say "Do you have the sheet music for that song?" because "Do you have the music sheet for that song?" would be referring to a definite object that the asker supposedly already knows about. We could technically say "Do you have *a* music sheet for that song?" but that semantic construct is never used because it's a bit too broad in the interpretation of what the "correct sheet" would be.

"*The* sheet music" refers to "the correct notation for your part of the song we're playing," where "the *music sheet*" would be "a specific piece of paper I gave you earlier that has music on it."

Comment: Well, what you say sounds logical. But only if we use other forms of music like 'sound music', or 'oral music', or 'formula music'. I mean, seems that we don't have these combinations (compound words), thus "music sheet" seems really more meaningful. But voteup for this nice analysis. :)

Comment: *Music sheet* would be essentially a *sheet*, albeit a musical one and I feel that musical aspect is not stressed enough in that term, while *sheet music* is still essentially *music*, but that comes or is written on a sheet. Also, we do have similarly constructed idioms such as: *elevator music*, *shopping music*, *chin music*.

Comment: To me, it's still like 'accounts payable' instead of 'payable accounts' in Accounting. I think there should be an etymology behind this combination. For example, maybe it comes from a language in which, noun comes before an adjective.

Comment: @NReilingh, I like your answer, however in your examples of 'fine print', 'fine' is a regular adjective (in the sense of small and delicate) and turning it around to 'print fine' puts it in a place of a noun (and takes the meaning of money you need to pay when you break some law or regulation); I think that OP was interested only in the cases where nouns are used as adjectives.

Comment: @NReilingh, I think your answer is slightly misleading. As a musician I know all about "sheet music" but have _never_ heard anyone refer to a "music sheet". (I know that Unreason has an ngram search showing that it does occur, but that doesn't mean it is in common usage.) _Also_ your discussion about "cases where the object itself comes second" seems to be overcomplicating this phrase: it is a straight forward adjective-noun combination - "sheet" (adjective) shows what sort of "music" (noun) we are talking about. Which is what your first sentence says -- you should have left it there!

Comment: @AAT You should check us out over at http://music.stackexchange.com! I agree it's probably not the best answer--I think I was squirming a little to try to get Saeed to see it my way. Please suggest an edit if you can improve it!

Comment: I believe the verbosity is useful here, as I don't find this matter trivial. I personally consider asking for "a music sheet" more clear than for "sheet music"- the former sounds like it relates to a single perceivable object, and the latter - to the whole type of music notation.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you offer half of the answer already:

> Isn't it a sheet (an object) that has an adjective of being related to music?

Now, imagining for a second that you don't know which term is an established term: *sheet music* or *music sheet*, you should admit that an *equally* relevant *question* is:

> Isn't it *music* that has an adjective *sheet*, signifying that it is related to a sheet (written to or read from it)?

To me it seems rather obvious that the principal noun here is *music* and that the *sheet* only determines the context. We are firstly talking about music and therefore the music remains the noun.

It is similar to these constructs: *piano music*, *elevator music*, *shopping music*, *chin music*, etc..

As for the term *music(al) sheet* look at the [results](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=music%20sheet,%20musical%20sheet&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) of the ngram search (you can explore the examples by clicking on the links in table below the graphs to see actual usage in books):

[image]

This shows that the actual terms *music sheet* and *musical sheet* are actually used sometimes, especially when referring to a single sheet of *sheet music* (or when the actual sheet is an object in the sentence). Still *sheet music* is appropriate when talking about the actual music written on the sheet and as such it is much more [common](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=music%20sheet,musical%20sheet,%20sheet%20music&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) (as a subject and consequently in the language).

As for etymology, [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sheet) only lists the date

> *sheet music* is from 1857

Comment: 'piano music' means 'music of piano'; likewise, 'elevator music' means 'music of elevator' or 'music played in elevator'. Thus none of these two examples have an adjective in them. They are just two nouns which describe something belongs to something else.

Comment: English can use nouns *as* adjectives, see for example http://english-zone.com/grammar/adjective3.html or http://www.usingenglish.com/glossary/noun-as-adjective.html If you understand that 'piano music' means 'music of piano' then you should have no problem with a concept that here 'piano' is a noun that is working as an adjective.

Comment: Nouns are used as attributes, as in _expiration date_.

Comment: attributes - adjectives, potato - potato.